# How to get more information about generic Velocity exception

Tags: spring, tomcat8, velocity

I have an `Exception rendering #parse(<template_name>)` in my Tomcat logs (catalina.out) from time to time. The problem is that it happens once every few days and I don't know how to get more information about it. I cannot even reproduce it. I loaded the page that throws this tens of times, and the template was parsed each time without issues.

I found nothing relevant in the other Tomcat logs either.

Any ideas about how to log more details or avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a velocity expert, but:

**catalina.out** is a file that is not configured with respect to the logging system of your application.

Velocity uses slf4j for logging, so the application probably does.
Try to configure the underlying logging system of the application to catch Velocity's exceptions and a stacktrace.

When velocity exception happens it probably gets logged somewhere (check out their sources, its an open source project, after all) - and see what logger do they use.

The chances are that configuring the logger and appender to get the messages from **org.apache.velocity** will do the job.